# Xorg mouse sensitivity

Tags: linux, mouse, xorg

Is there any analog of `xset m 4/3 7` in xorg config files?

I've tried different options of `InputClass` sections and noone is working, but `xset m` working properly.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "xorg config files"? Were you editing /etx/X11/xorg.conf or the files under /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/?

AFAIK, this sort of thing is no longer set by Xorg. Instead it is controlled through HAL. Not in all distros though...

In any case, the information on [this page](http://patrickmylund.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/) should help.

Alternatively, you can just add the xset command to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile (depending on your distribution).

The surest, if not the most elegant, solution is to create a sript called fixmouse.sh (or whatever you feel like) with these lines:

```
#/bin/bash
xset m 4/3 7
```

And add it to the startup programs of your Desktop Environment. Can't tell you how to do this because you give neither your distro nor your DE in your question.